# MuleSoft filter a json array by keys from another json array's list

Tags: arrays, json, dataweave, mulesoft

In MuleSoft/DataWeave I have a json array I need to filter by key values in another json list.
Here's the json I need to filter:

```
[
  {
    "order_by": "CDDASD",
    "product_no": "69843270432",
    "serial_number": "CD909837296",
    "place_of_origin": "SFG",
    "depot": "LK955",
    "quantity": "150"
  },
  {
    "order_by": "CDDPOI",
    "product_no": "74890327033",
    "serial_number": "CD909837297",
    "place_of_origin": "SVH",
    "depot": "MN822",
    "quantity": "900"
  },
  {
    "order_by": "CDDUYT",
    "product_no": "43720943334",
    "serial_number": "CD909837298",
    "place_of_origin": "SRF",
    "depot": "BV675",
    "quantity": "1200"
  }
]
```

When I make an API call I send the following json

```
{
  "FORMAT": [
    "order_by",
    "product_no",
    "serial_number"
  ]
}
```

I want the response to return only the key/value pairs in the first json that match whatever keys are specified in `FORMAT`. So with the above I expect a response like this:

```
[
      {
        "order_by": "CDDASD",
        "product_no": "69843270432",
        "serial_number": "CD909837296"
      },
      {
        "order_by": "CDDPOI",
        "product_no": "74890327033",
        "serial_number": "CD909837297"
      },
      {
        "order_by": "CDDUYT",
        "product_no": "43720943334",
        "serial_number": "CD909837298"
      }
    ]
```

I'm having trouble iterating through the values in `FORMAT` and then filtering the first json by those values.
I am not even sure what functions in DataWeave I should use. Should I use map on `FORMAT` and then filter on the first json? I keep getting errors about using arrays when an object is expected so I am at loss.
Apologies for the lack of code, I am too confused to know what I should be doing. I appreciate all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your payload is always going to be what you provided (not nested structure) then you can use [Map](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-map) function to iterate over your payload and then [filterObject](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-filterobject) to achieve your desired output

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var fields = {
  "FORMAT": [
    "order_by",
    "product_no",
    "serial_number"
  ]
}
---
payload map ((item) -> 
    item filterObject ((value, key) ->
    fields.FORMAT contains  (key as String) ))
```